# A question about Tukey HSD test

Tags: tukey-hsd-test

1. Does Tukey comparison in glht/multcomp package in R refers to Tukey
   HSD test?
2. Can I use the Tukey HSD test (for multiple comparisons)
   after applying the Robust technique (Such as Robust Anova, Robust Ancova)?
   (I just want to make sure that Tukey HSD test is not based on
   normality and equality of variances)

library(multcomp)
posthoc = glht(model, linfct = mcp(Tech="Tukey"))

Comment: Tukey HSD assumes normal data with equal variances, so if you needed to do robust ANOVA because those assumptions fail, HSD is not a good choice for post-hoc tests.  Maybe do robust paired comparisons and control family error rate with Bonferroni method.

Comment: @BruceET, thanks for the reply. Can I use robust paired comparisons for comparing the means, Also if Tukey HSD is not appropriate when there is a violation of assumption why lmrob function still works with tukey contrast? glht(fit1, linfct = mcp(Ethnic.Sex ="Tukey"))

Comment: Don't know; can only speculate: Maybe authors of pkg feel that there is some protection because HSD invoked only if grand hypothesis for main effect rejected. But theory I recall seeing to support HSD is based on max difference among several means of normal data with same variances and sample sizes. Wonder if authors use suitable more recent embellishments to HSD. I'd look at R documentation.